# How to handle "outside" click on Dialog (Modal)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, modal-dialog, material-ui

My box closes when clicking outside of the box making me lose all the input.
I want my box to close only when clicking on the cancel button.
I am not sure what is making it close when clicking outside. Any help?

I am using @material-ui/core

```
  _close() {
        DeviceCreationActions.close();
    }

render() {
        const actions = [
            <Button
                id="device-create-dialog-close"
                key="device-create-dialog-close"
                onClick={this._close}
            >
              {this.context.intl.formatMessage({id: 'Cancel'})}
            </Button>
        ];

        if (0 < this.state.stepIndex) {
            actions.push(<Button
                id="device-create-dialog-back"
                key="device-create-dialog-back"
                onClick={this._previousStep.bind(this)}
              >
                {this.context.intl.formatMessage({id: 'Back'})}
              </Button>
            );
        }

        if (
            (1 >= this.state.stepIndex && 0 < this.state['formStep' + this.state.stepIndex].length) ||
            (0 < this.state.stepIndex)
        ) {
            actions.push(<Button
                id="device-create-dialog-next"
                key="device-create-dialog-next"
                onClick={2 === this.state.stepIndex ? this._save.bind(this) : this._nextStep.bind(this)}
              >
                {this.context.intl.formatMessage({id: 2 === this.state.stepIndex ? 'Create' : 'Next'})}
              </Button>
            );
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the code in Box? or any more code involved?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I think what you need is `disableBackdropClick` passed down to `<Modal />` component

```
<Modal disableBackdropClick />
```

You can also disable close Dialog on Esc key press with `disableEscapeKeyDown` prop

Comment: This is deprecated now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65687053/how-to-disable-muibackdrop-in-muidialog-material-ui-react

Answer (score 143):

`disableBackdropClick` will not work in Material UI v5.

[Dialog API (next)](https://mui.com/api/dialog/)

You can use code from the migration guide to handle each closing source manually with the `onClose` `prop` by detecting the source of the closing event.

```
<Dialog onClose={handleClose} />
```

And use the handler to stop it

*Javascript:*

```js
const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason && reason === "backdropClick") 
        return;
    myCloseModal();
}
```

*Typescript:*

Add import to top of file:

```js
import type { DialogProps } from "@mui/material";
```

Then add the handler:

```js
const handleClose: DialogProps["onClose"] = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason && reason === "backdropClick")
        return;
    myCloseModal();
}
```

Comment: Nice this is the exact answer :)

Comment: or don't pass onClose

Comment: @ Code Ninja this might work, but you lose benefits like close on ESC click which I encountered

Comment: https://smartdevpreneur.com/how-to-disable-mui-dialog-backdrop-click/

Answer (score 23):

Just remove the `onClose` method

```
  <Dialog
     sx={{
       position: 'absolute',
       left: 300,
       top: 35
     }}
     maxWidth="lg"
    open={open}
    // onClose={handleClose}
   .....
```

Comment: Removing `onClose` also removes the ability to close a dialog by pressing ESC key

Comment: With this you completely lose the onClose handler

Answer (score 4):

```
const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason && reason == "backdropClick" && "escapeKeyDown") 
        return;
    myCloseModal();
}
```

This will prevent to modal to close on outside clicks and escape button

Answer (score 4):

since `disableBackdropClick` is deprecated in the newest versions of material ui so the easier way to remove `onClose` from the dialog properties and add a button on `DialogTitle` and fire your `handleClose` function after a click on the button that will set the state of open dialog to false

```js
<Dialog
  // onClose={handleClose} // the line to be removed
  open={dialog.open}
  fullWidth
  maxWidth="md"
  >
  <DialogTitle
    sx={{
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }}
  >
    <Typography
      variant="h5"
      textAlign="center"
      component="h1"
      gutterBottom
      sx={{
        pl: 2,
      }}
    >
      {dialog.action === 'add'
        ? 'Ajouter une question'
        : 'Editer la question'}
    </Typography>
    
    {/*Fire handleClose after a click on close button*/}
    <IconButton onClick={handleClose} sx={{ ml: 'auto' }}>
      <CloseIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </DialogTitle>
  <QuestionForm
    dimensionId={dimensionId}
    action={dialog.action}
    questionData={dialog.data}
    handleClose={handleClose}
    setQuestions={setQuestions}
    setRows={setRows}
  />
</Dialog>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your Dialog tag remove the onClose event function. Then just add a button below let's say 'Cancel' then you can call function to close the dialog

```
const handleClose = () => {
 setOpen(false)
}

<Dialog
  fullWidth={true}
  open={open}
>
....
 <DialogActions>
    <Button onClick={handleClose} disabled={loading}>Cancel</Button>
 </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add "disableBackdropClick" prop in your component. This will restrict(disable) outside click of your popup or dialog.

```
    //Example
    <DialogCss
      style={{ zIndex: 2000 }}
      open={ruleBoxOpen}
      keepMounted
      onClose={() => setRuleBoxOpen(false)}
      aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
      aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
      disableBackdropClick
    >
```

Answer (score 1):

###### if backdrop/outside of dialog click then do nothing/don't close dialog. making sure the process is completed properly

```
const handleMeetingCreateDialogClose = (event, reason) => {
        if (reason && reason === "backdropClick")   return; 
        setFormData(formInitial);
        setMeetingCreateDialogOpen(false);
};
```

```
<Dialog open={meetingCreateDialogOpen} onClose={handleMeetingCreateDialogClose}  disableEscapeKeyDown  >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a similar component, like this one :

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";

export function CustomDialog(props: {
  open: boolean;
  children: ReactNode;
}) {
  if (!props.open) return <></>;
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "fixed",
        top: "50%",
        left: "50%",
        transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This was my problem as well and no one seems to answer it quite well. This is what I did.

Remove the `onClose` from the `<Dialog >` wrapper, i.e. this is how the `<Dialog>` might look:

```
<Dialog
    sx={{
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 300,
        top: 35
    }}
    maxWidth="lg"
    open={open}
    // onClose={handleClose}      <<<<<<<
    ....
>
```

And finally, add the `handleClose` function to the `onClick` event of the `close` button.

```
<Button
    color="primary"
    size="large"
    type="submit"
    variant="contained"
    onClick={handleClose}
>
    Close
</Button>
```

Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my full solution to remove the flag because was descoped, but keeping the functionality.

This is the dialog:

```
  <Dialog
    open={showModal}
    disableBackdropClick
    disableEscapeKeyDown
    aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
    aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
    onClose={handleDlgClose}
  >
    <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
      The title of the dialog
    </DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
      <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
        The message is here
        {bestScore} moves.
      </DialogContentText>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
      <Button onClick={handleOk} color="primary">
        Restart
      </Button>
    </DialogActions>
  </Dialog>
enter code here
```

The function that intercepts the close event and if it comes from a click in the background and returns without closing the dialog:

```
const handleDlgClose = (event, reason) => {
  if (reason && reason == "backdropClick") {
    console.log('backdropClicked. Not closing dialog.')
    return;
  }

  setShowModal(false);
}
```

then handler and removing the property:

...

https://dev.to/teaganga/handle-dialogdisablebackdropclick-descoped-property-warning-in-mui-v5-2i35