# How do I prevent Material UI Dialog from being dismissed upon clicking the backdrop?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a React JS app that uses the Dialog component and I cannot seem to find any documentation on how I can prevent the dialog from being automatically dismissed by merely clicking the backdrop. I have an explicit action within the dialog that I want to use for control of the dismissal.

I have tried reading the docs and of course searching here but am not finding anything helpful or that contains an example. Any help is appreciated; this is my first time using React.

```
<Dialog onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title" open={open}>
  <DialogTitle id="simple-dialog-title">Uploading Media To Server</DialogTitle>
  <React.Fragment>
    <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center">          
        <img src={LoadingGif} width="150" />
    </Grid>
  </React.Fragment>
</Dialog>
```

There was mention of this being a possible duplicate of [How to handle "outside" click on Dialog (Modal) with material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329278) but do not find it helpful as I am using a Dialog component instead of a Modal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle "outside" click on Dialog (Modal) with material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329278/how-to-handle-outside-click-on-dialog-modal-with-material-ui)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Material 4**

Try this:

```
<Dialog onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title" 
  open={open} onBackdropClick="false">
   <DialogTitle id="simple-dialog-title">Uploading Media To Server</DialogTitle>
   <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center">          
        <img src={LoadingGif} width="150" />
      </Grid>
   </React.Fragment>
</Dialog>
```

You can also achieve it setting `disableBackdropClick="true"`, which maybe is more appropriate for your use case.

**Material 5**

`onBackdropClick` and `disableBackdropClick` were deprecated in Material v5, use this instead:

```
   <Dialog onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title" 
      open={open}>
       <DialogTitle id="simple-dialog-title">Uploading Media To Server</DialogTitle>
       <React.Fragment>
          <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center">          
            <img src={LoadingGif} width="150" />
          </Grid>
       </React.Fragment>
    </Dialog>
```

And checking whether the backdrop was clicked in the `onClose` handler:

*Javascript:*

```js
const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason && reason === "backdropClick") 
        return;
    myCloseModal();
}
```

*Typescript:*

Add import to top of file:

```js
import type { DialogProps } from "@mui/material";
```

Then add the handler:

```js
const handleClose: DialogProps["onClose"] = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason && reason === "backdropClick")
        return;
    myCloseModal();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I saw the onBackdropClick event but didn't think to put a string-based 'false' as the value. Thanks David

Comment: They changed the API. Refer to this comment to see how it's done now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67745133/6434590

Comment: @DavidG. - perhaps you might consider updating this post to include the latest v5 information?  I can't upvote this today because it is out of date, but if it had the most recent API I certainly could...

Comment: @AlexanderNied Updated, I thought it was redundant since there was the post I mentioned with the same solution, but I agree this is more visible.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove onClose prop to Dialog component, it will solve your problem.
Also you can trigger handleClose on cancel button.
It was a quick fix for me.

```
<Dialog aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title" open={open}>
  <DialogTitle id="simple-dialog-title">Uploading Media To Server</DialogTitle>
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center">          
        <img src={LoadingGif} width="150" />
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are using Typescript and may run into issues with the accepted answer (particularly as it pertains to handling both background/escape and button closes, this was my solution:

```
type LookupValues<Values> = Values[keyof Values];
const CLOSE_REASON = {
    BUTTON: 'closeButtonClick',
    BACKDROP: 'backdropClick',
    ESCAPE: 'escapeKeyDown',
} as const;

type CloseReason = LookupValues<typeof CLOSE_REASON>;
const IGNORED_REASONS: CloseReason[] = [CLOSE_REASON.BACKDROP, CLOSE_REASON.ESCAPE];

type CloseHandler = (event: object, reason: CloseReason) => void;


type ModalProps = {
  onClose: () => void;
  isOpen: boolan;
}
const DialogComponent: FunctionComponent<{   }> = ({ isOpen, onClose }) => {
  const handleClose: CloseHandler = (_, reason) => {
    if (IGNORED_REASONS.includes(reason)) {
      return;
    }
    onClose();
  };
  return (
    <Dialog 
      aria-labelledby={ELEMENT_ID_LOOKUP.MODAL_TITLE} 
      open={isOpen} 
      onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle id={ELEMENT_ID_LOOKUP.MODAL_TITLE}>Title</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          { /* content */}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={e => handleClose(e, CLOSE_REASON.BUTTON)}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```