# How to disable MuiBackdrop in Muidialog (Material UI react)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Whenever I called the MuiDialog tag in material UI, It's always render a div tag for Backdrop like this:

```
<div class="MuiDialog-root> 
    //THIS IS IT
    <div class="MuiBackdrop-root" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;"></div>
</div>
```

I know that in MuiDialog, we can set attributes for Backdrop like this:

```
<MuiDialog BackDropProps={{//WRITE SOMETHING HERE}}
>
</MuiDialog>
```

But I don't know what to fill in to make It disappear.
Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle "outside" click on Dialog (Modal)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329278/how-to-handle-outside-click-on-dialog-modal)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the `hideBackdrop` prop to `true`.

If you look at the bottom of the dialog docs on material UI it has this:

> Inheritance.
> The props of the Modal component are also available.
> You can take advantage of this behavior to target nested components.

`hideBackdrop` is a prop in the Modal component.

Comment: Try setting hideBackdrop to true in the dialog it should work just fine

Comment: wjpayne83, It's really weird that It did work somehow but the document didn't mention about It. Thank you :-). Anyway, If you update your answer, I will mark It :-)

Comment: You could do it both ways, using `BackDropProps` or by hiding the backdrop as suggested in this answer.

Comment: No worries! glad to help, I updated my answer.