# Material UI modal snapshot is different in server (CI) compared to locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have a jest/react testing library snapshot that fails in server but locally the snapshot does not get updated (even when I run with --ci option).

I'm talking about a modal component from material ui.

```
import {Modal} from '@mui/material';
(...)

<Modal
      open={isOpen}
      onClose={toggleModal}
      disableEscapeKeyDown
      hideBackdrop={false}> // also attempted to remove this prop, since default is false but makes no diference
      (...)
</Modal>
```

Snapshot Test:

```
it('should match snapshot', () => {
    renderComponent();
    expect(wrapper.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Package.json scripts to run the tests:

```
(...)
"test": "jest",
"test:ci": "jest --ci",
```

Locally the snapshot looks like this, and never gets updated (tried with -- -u option):

```
(...)
class="MuiBackdrop-root css-i9fmh8-MuiBackdrop-root-MuiModal-backdrop"
```

But on the server the snapshot gets updated to this (it executes with "npm run test:ci"):

```
(...)
-       class="MuiBackdrop-root css-i9fmh8-MuiBackdrop-root-MuiModal-backdrop"
+       class="MuiBackdrop-root MuiModal-backdrop css-i9fmh8-MuiBackdrop-root-MuiModal-backdrop"
```

As you can see MuiModal-backdrop gets introduced in the middle of class name, and I don't have control hover this div since it's hidden and generated by material ui itself as I can confirm in the local snapshot:

```
<div
      aria-hidden="true"
      class="MuiBackdrop-root css-i9fmh8-MuiBackdrop-root-MuiModal-backdrop"
      style="opacity: 1; webkit-transition: opacity 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms; transition: opacity 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;"
    />
```

I'm using the same node version as in CI environment which is v16.18.1. Any idea about what this could be?

Comment: `BackdropProps ={{ style: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }, }}` You should do soemthing with `BackdropProps`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65687053/how-to-disable-muibackdrop-in-muidialog-material-ui-react Would this help?

Comment: @DreamBold The backdrop, is for disabling interaction below the modal. So I'm not supposed to hide it..

Comment: @DreamBold that doesn't seem to be available for the Modal Component of material ui

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to update material ui to the latest version, in this case:
"@mui/material": "^5.11.2",

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).